# Android execute receiver several times a day

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

To be more exact, I want to do following: AlarmReceiver-Broadcaster should be executed every day two times: Is TimerTask still the better solution?

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);

    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);

    Intent intentAlarm2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentAlarm2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Comment: what do u mean by several times? as in at specific times / intervals ?

Comment: E.g. I want to play the same sound after 3 seconds and then again after 8 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [TimerTask in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html). Here is an example how to use it [example](http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/).

Comment: Well I want to execute it everyday on specific times to be exact

Comment: You can schedule any interval with timer task. and may be include this in a background service. I dont know how your code is organized but the correct way of doing things repeatedly after regular intervals of time is through TimerTask

Comment: There should be a way with AlarmManager as well..., no?

Comment: Well of course there will be other ways. But then there are right ways of doing things.